# SSIS one flat file source 3 columns into 2 union all

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a delimited flat file that has 3 columns:

```
NEW #     DETAIL    OLD #
------    ------    ------
111111    AAAA      123456
222222    BBBB
333333    CCCC      987654
```

I need my output to be

```
#         DETAIL   
------    ------
111111    AAAA      
222222    BBBB
333333    CCCC      
123456    AAAA
987654    CCCC
```

I need to ignore nulls in the OLD # column.

I'm not sure the best way to accomplish this.  Union All and/or merge seem to work if you have multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

The general concept is that you will want to [Unpivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx). Jason Strate has a really good article on it with his [31 days of SSIS series](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-unpivot-transformation-1131/).

The basic idea is that you want to keep the DETAIL column and let the other two flow into it. Unpivot is the native operation to normalize the data.

## Source

I used a query as it was faster to gin up and I added in a row with an explicit NULL value.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('111111','AAAA','123456')
,   ('222222','BBBB','')
,   ('333333','CCCC','987654')
,   ('444444','DDDD',NULL)
) D([NEW #], [DETAIL],[OLD #]);
```

## Unpviot

The operation will unpivot the data. This eliminates NULL values but retains empty strings. This may or may not be the outcome you desire.

[image]

## Results

At this point, you can see we have the empty string row. You can address this in two ways, I'll let you pick your approach.

- Upstream - scrub empty strings to NULL for elimination
- Downstream - use a Conditional Split to remove the rows with empty Number values

[image]

### Biml

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, describes the platform for business intelligence. Here, we're going to use it to describe the ETL. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com), is a free add on for Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT that addresses a host of shortcomings with it. Specifically, we're going to use the ability to transform a Biml file describing ETL into an SSIS package. This has the added benefit of providing you a mechanism for being able to generate exactly the solution I'm describing versus clicking through many tedious dialogue boxes.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=tempdb" Name="CM_OLE" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package 
            ConstraintMode="Linear" 
            Name="so_25670727">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Combine all">
                    <Transformations>
                        <!--
                        Generate some source data. Added a row with an explicit NULL
                        as no real testing is done unless we have to deal with NULLs
                        -->
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="OLE_SRC Query">
                            <DirectInput>
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('111111','AAAA','123456')
,   ('222222','BBBB','')
,   ('333333','CCCC','987654')
,   ('444444','DDDD',NULL)
) D([NEW #], [DETAIL],[OLD #]);                                
                            </DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <!--
                        Unpivot the data. Combine NEW # and OLD # into a single column called Number.
                        A "Pivot Key Value" column will also be generated that identifies where the value came
                        from.
                        -->
                        <Unpivot Name="UP Detail">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="DETAIL" TargetColumn="DETAIL"/>
                                <Column SourceColumn="NEW #" TargetColumn="Number" PivotKeyValue="NEW #"/>
                                <Column SourceColumn="OLD #" TargetColumn="Number" PivotKeyValue="OLD #"/>
                            </Columns>
                        </Unpivot>
                        <!--
                        Put something here so we can attach a data viewer
                        Notice, the NULL does not show in the output but the empty string does.
                        Depending on your tolerance, you will want to either
                        * Upstream - scrub empty strings to NULL for elimination 
                        * Upstream - convert NULL to empty string for preservation
                        * Downstream - use a Conditional Split to remove the rows with empty Number columns
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER DataViewer">
                        </DerivedColumns>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```